# Hack: Duplicates in java.util.TreeSet?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a simple class

```
public class A {
    int val;
    public A(int val) {this.val = val;}
}
```

I store `A` instances in a `java.util.TreeSet` like:

```
SortedSet<A> ss = new TreeSet<A>(new Comparator<A>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.val, o2.val);
    }
});
```

Only to find later that `A` instances with the same `val` values cannot coexist in `TreeSet`.

I need `TreeSet` because I want:

- Quick Insertion
- Quick Removal
- Quick Query of Element with Minimum `val`

Since the equality completely depends on the return value 0 of `compare()` and how we implement it, is there a hacking way that allow instances with the same value of `val` to coexist in `TreeSet`?

My workaround is to return a stable non-zero value if `val` are equal, but it proves to be unstable.

```
SortedSet<ListNode> ss = new TreeSet<ListNode>(new Comparator<ListNode>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ListNode o1, ListNode o2) {
        if (o1.val != o2.val) return Integer.compare(o1.val, o2.val);
        return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode(); // not to return 0
    }
});
```

Or should I just switch to another data structure? (if there exists some substitute better than R-B Tree)

And, Oh Geez, I know [modeling the mathematical set abstraction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is cool and everyone here loves it.

**Conclusion**: use [priority queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Comment: @dehasi, how will that help? If the values are equal, the hashCode and equals should be same as well

Comment: @Anon, I've just misunderstood the problem. It is not possible to put the same values to a set. Just because it's..  Set. Set contains only different values. Maybe `Multiset` from `Guava` will help.

Comment: @dehasi check out the `final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key)` method in `java.util.TreeMap` source code... I'm pretty sure `equals` and `hashCode` are only crucial to `HashMap` and `HashSet` in terms of `Map` and `Set` implementation.

Comment: @CedricSun what is the complexity you are looking at i.e. what is "Quick" here: 
    Quick Insertion
    Quick Removal
    Quick Query of Element with Minimum val

Comment: @CedricSun it you need query minimum, you need a Heap, not a Set at all, try [MinMaxPriorityQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html)

Comment: @Anon By quick I mean being better than linear ... such as logarithm to the scale of the problem - the number of instances in set

Comment: @dehasi Oh, the heap... I think I COMPLETELY forget it... That would be an answer to my problem, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @CedricSun you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

That's what I wanted to say... why not use a `Queue` and especially a `PriorityQueue` that the documentation says to have :

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the enqueuing and dequeuing methods: offer, poll, remove and add; linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods, peek, and size.

The diff in `PriorityQueue` vs `Tree` is also that the first one is more light-weight as it uses a `binary heap` as opposed to `red-black tree`; so the `PriorityQueue` will use an array to store it's data that is not that hard to understand.

Also notice that if you populate your `PriorityQueue` often with high priority tasks - your low priority tasks could wait a lot of time before they are processed.

Comment: Yes...There has been a long time since the last time I did exercises about data structure and algorithm, and in Java for the first time. I was actually solving [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/#/description). Hope this post can help people with the same confusion :)

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you want different A instances to coexist in your set even if they share the same val, and not to add the same A instance more than once.

```
A a = new A(1);
A b = new A(1);
A c = new A(2);
A d = c;
ss.add(a);
ss.add(b);
ss.add(c);
ss.add(d);
```

After that, you want `ss` to contain three instances: two 1 values and one 2 value (because a and b are different instances, c and d contain the same). That is what your code will do (if you don't override the hashCode() method from Object).

Just one improvement: `o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode()` might produce arithmetic overflow, better use `Integer.compare()` for that part, too. E.g. 2000000000 - (-2000000000) will give a negative result although the first number is greater. And that will cause all Comparator-based structures to behave strangely.

Comment: The overflow is not the only problem with the OP's approach - there are also hash collisions (if the size of the collection is large enough for performance of insertions and removals to matter).

Comment: @Hulk: You are right. There's one aspect where my experience from 32-bit Java isn't valid with 64-bit java any more :-(. With 32-bit java, the standard JRE's Object.hashCode() returned the internal address ("This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer [...]"), and as a result, Object.hashCode() never collided, as addresses and integers had the same size. But with 64-bit addresses and 32-bit integers, this is no longer possible, and even Object.hashCode() can potentially create collisions.